# Adding friends script with php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have made simple script which allowing users to add another users as their friends. So far everything work as expecting. User loggin into his account then browse profile page of another user and there is button `add as friend` and user can add it. This is done via ajax/php/mysql.

Currently I successfully show message to user only when he add another user as friend and if when they are already friends. But when he try to add himself he got message `You're now friends`. Here is the php part which check if the user is in his friend list or not. If is he get message that they are friends and if is not he get message that they are now friends.

```
if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {

    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];   

            $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE friend_id= ? and user_id = ?');
            $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $value->bindParam(2, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);             
            $value->execute();
            $result = $value->fetch();    

     if( $result > 0) {
        echo 'Already friends';         
     }
     else 
     {
        if ( $_SESSION['id'] != $_POST['id'] ){
            $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
            $user_id = $_SESSION['id']; 

            $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO user_friends (friend_id, user_id, friendsSince)
                                  VALUES (:friend_id, :user_id, NOW())");   
            $query -> execute(array(
                          ":friend_id"  => $friend_id,
                          ":user_id"    => $user_id,
            ));     
     } 
else 
{ 
   echo ''; 
}
}
```

and this is the ajax part which send $id to the script

```
    $('.newFriend, .buttons').click(function(){
    $.post('misc/add_friend.php', 
    { 
        "id": $(this).attr('id'),

    },

    function(data){
        if(data == 0){
            $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Already friends!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }           
        else {
             $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: red">You're now friends!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }
     });
});
```

The problem is when current user click on the button and try to add himself as a friend. The script check the table for the ID and see that it is not stored then the script going to insert this user and the current user got message that he successfully added the user as friend.

I can't figured out how to show message to him that he can't add himself. Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: you can set current id in session or cookie and compare that id when you call ajax if post id and session id are same then send him a message that you can not add himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return a specific message for each condition from PHP, I've added a new response for when a user is trying to add themselves and another for when the user is added successfully. Then you use JS to check the response.

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST["id"])) {

    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];
    $user_id   = $_SESSION['id'];

    $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE friend_id= ? and user_id = ?');
    $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->bindParam(2, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->execute();
    $result = $value->fetch();

    if ($result > 0) {
        echo 'Already friends';
    } else {
        if ($_SESSION['id'] != $_POST['id']) {
            $friend_id = $_POST['id'];
            $user_id   = $_SESSION['id'];

            $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user_friends (friend_id, user_id, friendsSince)
                                  VALUES (:friend_id, :user_id, NOW())");
            $query->execute(array(
                    ":friend_id" => $friend_id,
                    ":user_id" => $user_id
            ));

            echo 'Added as friend';
        } else {
            echo 'Trying to add themselves';
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
$('.newFriend, .buttons').click(function() {
    $.post('misc/add_friend.php',
            {
                "id": $(this).attr('id')
            },
            function (response) {

                switch (response) {
                    case 'Already friends':
                        $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Already friends!</div>');
                        $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                            $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'Trying to add themselves':
                        $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: red">You\'re trying to add yourself</div>');
                        $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                            $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'Added as friend':
                        $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: red">You\'re now friends!</div>');
                        $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                            $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I actually trying but got this in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @JordanVit I've updated the JS that error should be gone

Comment: Now is ok and I got proper message. Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should not be showing an add as friend button against the users own name in the first place.

But to solve your problem as posted

```
if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {

    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];   

    if ($user_id === $friend_id) {
        echo ''; 
    }
    else {
            $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE   friend_id= ? and user_id = ?');
            $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $value->bindParam(2, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);             
            $value->execute();
            $result = $value->fetch();    

     if( $result > 0) {
        echo 'Already friends';         
     }
     else 
     {
        if ( $_SESSION['id'] != $_POST['id'] ){
            $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
            $user_id = $_SESSION['id']; 

            $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO user_friends (friend_id, user_id, friendsSince)
                                  VALUES (:friend_id, :user_id, NOW())");   
            $query -> execute(array(
                          ":friend_id"  => $friend_id,
                          ":user_id"    => $user_id,
            ));     
        } 
       else 
       { 
           echo ''; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Well I didn't think that I can actually hide the button on the current user.